# undefined method `returning' for WillPaginate:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, will-paginate

I was upgrading a Rails 2 application to Rails 3, when I execute `rails console` it throws this:

```
$ rails c production
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/will_paginate-2.3.12/lib/will_paginate.rb:39:in `enable_activerecord': undefined method `returning' for WillPaginate:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/will_paginate-2.3.12/lib/will_paginate.rb:88
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /home/neoriddle/proyectos/interkids/config/application.rb:7
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:21
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Update will_paginate gem.

Method `#returning` has been deprecated in favor of method `#tap`. Looks like the old version of will_paginate gem that you're using still uses that deprecated method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that was true.

Here my details...

I change in `Gemfile` this line:

```
gem 'will_paginate', '2.3.12'
```

with this line:

```
gem 'will_paginate', '>=3.0.pre'
```

Then I update `Gemfile.lock` with this:

```
bundle update will_paginate
```

And I get this:

```
$ bundle update will_paginate
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
...
Installing will_paginate (3.0.2) 
Updating .gem files in vendor/cache
  * will_paginate-3.0.2.gem
Removing outdated .gem files from vendor/cache
  * will_paginate-2.3.12.gem
Your bundle is updated! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

and this error were solved.